# How to fix the error giving doctrine2 migration in symfony2

Tags: mysql, database-design, web-applications, data-modeling

I had deleted my database and the i restored it for my synfony and doctrine2 app.

Now i am getting all sort of errors like

> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename
>   of './mytable' to './Acmes/#sql2-38b-19ce68a' (errno: 152)

Now how can i go back. My data is not important so it will be ok doctrine can regenerate the tables.

How can i do that

Comment: same error when exucting my migrations. it works well locally with the same database, that's strange. did you figure it out ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some tables/relations with the same name.
Do a `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` (:update or :create, depending on your situation) and check the generated SQL.